# Limit of a polynomials over e^x

Tags: limits

Will the limit as x approaches infinity of a polynomial over an exponential ever tend to infinity? I know the limit as x approaches infinity of x^2/e^x tends to 0, but will we ever be able to generate a power to the x large enough that it dominates over the exponential and doesn't tend to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Never. For any polynomial $P$ of degree $n$, apply L'hospital's rule $n$ times to $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{P(x)}{e^x}$

Comment: I understand we can apply L'hospital's rule and the polynomial will eventually end up a constant. But, even if we used the largest number known to man in the degree of the polynomial, it would still tend to 0? Would it not be possible to generate a number that essentially dominates the infinity, or not even dominate but reach a limit >0?

Comment: @raveen fix any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to be the degree of the polynomial $P$. You can take $n$ as big as you want. When you do $P^{(n+1)},$ you get constant $0$, and $e^{x}$ remains $e^{x}$.